# I lost my character in Terraria, how can I get it back?

Tags: steam, terraria

I was playing Terraria when my pc overheated and then shutdown. The next time I opened the game my character disappeared/deleted itself, I tried to recover the character by going to my Terraria game file and deleting then restoring the .plr file with no result. Did I do something wrong? Is there any other way to restore the character?

I'd be very thankful if you could help me. If there is no way to get it back, then that's ok thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your savegame is corrupt. The only solution to that, is to restore a previous savegame. You'll lose some progress, but it's still better than to lose everything.

If you're playing on Windows and have enabled OneDrive's [Folder Backup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-your-documents-pictures-and-desktop-folders-with-onedrive-d61a7930-a6fb-4b95-b28a-6552e77c3057) feature before your savegame got corrupted, you can easily [restore a previous version of your savegame](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-a-previous-version-of-a-file-stored-in-onedrive-159cad6d-d76e-4981-88ef-de6e96c93893?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). Each version should have a timestamp to help you identify a version that is uncorrupted. You can find your savegame in:
`OneDrive\Documents\My Games\Terraria`

If you don't use OneDrive (you're not on Windows or don't want to use OneDrive), you'll need to restore your savegame from a backup instead. Obviously, this is only possible if you have made at least one backup before your savegame got corrupted.

If you don't have a backup, then I strongly recommend you consider making one to avoid a situation like this in the future. Both Windows and macOS can make hourly automatic backups. Windows 10 has [File History](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-history-in-windows-5de0e203-ebae-05ab-db85-d5aa0a199255), while macOS has [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250).

Comment: I made a backup but that "backfired"...... ok sorry for the dad joke back there

Comment: @JustinCatLicks, I'm sorry your backup didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was deleted and you can't restore it, I don't believe there is any way to get it back.

If I misunderstood the question and you still have access to the .plr file in `Documents > My Games > Terraria > Players`, however, you might be able to restore it by right-clicking it and opening `Properties > Previous Versions`. If there are any previous versions listed under 'File versions:', then you can restore the file back to there.

As I said earlier though, if you don't have access to the file and it isn't backed up to Steam Cloud, there aren't really any ways to get it back.

*(As a side note, if you remember what that character had, you could create a new one and use an inventory editor to get your items back)*